# Moving postgres data folder on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I have a web application querying a Postgresql database (successfully) and I'm looking to move the data folder from location `/var/lib/postgres/9.3/main` to a customisable location.

Right now I'm prevented from even copying the folder due to permission errors, but I can't assign myself the permissions because that breaks the postgres server.

(I broke the server by running `sudo chown <username> -R /var/lib/postgres/9.3/main` - which worked as a command but stopped the postgres server from working)

I would simply create a new folder and change the location there, but I'll lose the current instance of my database if that was done.

How can I move the current folder to a new location, so that I can point to it in the `.conf` file? I need to explicitly move the folder, I can't create a new DB.

Comment: Why you need to move them? Most likely moving the data dir is a wrong answer to your question

Comment: @frlan my web app is being run off a linux VM, and I'm querying it from a windows machine via an IP. I'd like to be able to put the data onto a shared folder on the Windows machine and have a light(er) VM, rather than a 300GB instance of Linux which is only used as a web server.

Comment: @frlan believe me I know that moving the data is the wrong way about it, but it's taken weeks to get my data to the current state it's in, I can't restart that process.

Comment: If your issue is not having permissions, then wouldn't `sudo cp ...` be what you need? Once you're root, it doesn't usually matter who owns the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can just copy or move the directory, including all subdirs and files
  `cp -rp` or `mv` should be enough for this.
- Postgres must **not be running** while you are messing with the files
- The base of the data-drectory (PG_DATA) must be **owned by postgres** and have **file mode 0700** . (when not: pg will refuse to start)
- [the rest of the files must at least be readable/writeble by postgres]
- the new location must also be known to the startup process (in `/etc/init.d/` and (possibly) in the postgres.conf file within the data directory. (for the log file location)